# Get true background color of a transparent element that is positioned absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a transparent element like that is positioned absolutely

> header {   position: absolute;   top: 0px;   width: 100%; }

... and it's on top of a colored div.

How do I get the color of the div below of a absolutely positioned transparent div with javascript?

This is the transparent div (the navbar):
[image]

This is the navbar when you scroll down a little bit:
[image]

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Hello!
Glad you took the time to reply Paulie_D.
1
Here is what I tried before submitting the question:
I tried using getComputedStyle and getting the background-color of the transparent div, but since it is **positioned absolutely** this does not work.

Looking forward to other solutions :)

Comment: @Paulie_D (mentioning you so you see my comment above)

Comment: @KasparNoor please add what you've tried into the question itself using the code snippet tool.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have to actually capture a "screenshot" and look at how the page is finally rendered. As far as I know, that is the only way.

Basically you would need to check the rendered color of a single pixel. Not knowing *why* you want to do this is critical in is this necessary or not.

One way to achieve this is to use something like https://html2canvas.hertzen.com to take a screenshot of the rendered page, put that into a `<canvas>` element and then once you have that, check the color of a pixel you know to be inside the header; check https://jsfiddle.net/ourcodeworld/8swevoxo/ for an example.